# What part of speech is "that" in each of the following sentences that mean the same?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> It was all planned well before today that I can be sure about.

Here I believe that *that* is subordinating conjunction.

> It was all planned well before today; I can be sure about that.

Here I believe that *that* is pronoun, hence the need for the semicolon to separate the two coordinating clauses.

And are they both right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: _That_ is a demonstrative pronoun in both cases. There should be a comma after _today_ in the first one, to emphasize the fact that _that_ is stressed, but it's just a fronted object in apposition with the previous clause. It functions like a conjunction does, to introduce a clause, but so do complementizers and many other constructions, so it's nothing special.

Comment: Wouldn't the first alternative also require a semicolon?

Comment: "That" It means you are talking about something particular !

Comment: @EdwinAshworth surely a comma would be better?

Comment: The particular punctuation is determined by the intonation; but **something** is required. Which [punctuation mark](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) to use is strictly a technological question, though, and has nothing to do with language.

Comment: The punctuation is mentioned in the OP, and punctuation is a valid area for discussion according to the rules of the website - I'd have thought that using a comma here would be an example of a comma-splice.

Comment: Without punctuation, the first example not only sounds awkward, but it doesn't suggest the same meaning to me: I read “that I can be sure about” as an awkward variant of “as far as I'm aware.”

Comment: For the two sentences to have roughly the same meaning you should punctuate the first as: "It was all planned well before today; _that_ I can be sure about." the second sentence has inverted OSV-style word order.

Comment: Isn't it a conjunction in the first example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The word "that" is used identically in both sentences. Since it is not functioning as a subordinator, and the writer is linking two independent clauses, a semi-colon is required in both cases. Edwin is right: using a comma before "that" would create a run-on.

That said, it doesn't mean that a writer might not chose a comma instead. It only means that, given the rules of formal written English, a semi-colon (or a period) would be the conventional choice.

Answer (score 1):

Edwin Ashworth is correct.  In the first sentence, you must join the two independent clauses with a semi-colon (or a comma and a fanboys conjunction).  A comma is not sufficient to join two independent clauses.

Answer (score 0):

As John commented, *that* is a pronoun in each case. The confusion around whether it is a subordinating conjunction most likely stems from other grammar issues in the sentence. Quoting John's comment:

> There should be a comma after *today* in the first one, to emphasize the fact that *that* is stressed, but it's just a fronted object in apposition with the previous clause. It functions like a conjunction does, to introduce a clause, but so do complementizers and many other constructions, so it's nothing special.